# Is there a simple way in scala to cut x chars from a string from right to left?

Tags: java, scala

I have a `val str = "12345678910111213"`

What I want to do is, `if (str.length > 13)` return `"5678910111213"`

else return the number...

what is the best scala approach to solve it?

tnx

Comment: Do u have to use `scala` or will regular `java` work?

Comment: prefer scala but any solution will be accepted :) @brso05

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can treat a `String` as a `Seq[Char]`:

```
"12345678910111213".takeRight(13)
```

Comment: The [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_4.html) show: `s takeRight n` - `A collection consisting of the last n elements of xs (or, some arbitrary n elements, if no order is defined).
` . I wonder on the history of its naming - why not `takeLastN`?

Comment: Arguably, the `N` in `LastN` is not exactly pretty. In contrast, `takeRight` is in accordance with other methods such as `foldRight`, `reduceRight`, `scanRight`.